# How to specify ElasticSearch copy_to order?

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch has the ability to copy values to other fields (at index time), enabling you to search on multiple fields as if it were one field ([Core Types: copy_to](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-core-types.html)).

However, there doesn't seem to be any way to specify the order in which these values should be copied. This could be important when phrase matching:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://10.11.12.13:9200/helloworld'
curl -XPUT 'http://10.11.12.13:9200/helloworld'
# copy_to is ordered alphabetically!
curl -XPUT 'http://10.11.12.13:9200/helloworld/_mapping/people' -d '
{
  "people": {
    "properties": {
      "last_name": {
        "type": "string",
        "copy_to": "full_name"
      },
      "first_name": {
        "type": "string",
        "copy_to": "full_name"
      },
      "state": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "city": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "full_name": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
'

curl -X POST "10.11.12.13:9200/helloworld/people/dork" -d '{"first_name": "Jim", "last_name": "Bob", "state": "California", "city": "San Jose"}'
curl -X POST "10.11.12.13:9200/helloworld/people/face" -d '{"first_name": "Bob", "last_name": "Jim", "state": "California", "city": "San Jose"}'


curl "http://10.11.12.13:9200/helloworld/people/_search" -d '
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "full_name": {
        "query":    "Jim Bob"
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Only "Jim Bob" is returned; it seems that the fields are copied in field-name alphabetical order.

How would I switch the **copy_to** order such that the "Bob Jim" person would be returned?

Comment: That has to do with your query, you are specifying that you only want "Jim Bob" to be returned. Change your query to a match query and both will be returned. Or to be stricter create a bool query with two clauses for both phrases, "Jim Bob" and "Bob Jim".

Comment: I'm not sure my question is clear; the field generated by copy_to is clearly ordered, it's the generated field I want to change, not the query.

Comment: "Only "Jim Bob" is returned", that is because you are only searching for "Jim Bob". Change your query term to "Bob Jim", and that document will be returned. What is not clear to me is what you are trying to achieve with the ordering.

Comment: The fact that "Jim Bob" is returned is a sign that the field, full_name, contains first_name, followed by last_name. I can see that my example is contributing to the confusion, I'll update it.

Answer (score 3):

This is more deterministically controlled by registering a [transform script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html) in your mapping.

something like this:

```
"transform" : [
    {"script": "ctx._source['full_name'] = [ctx._source['first_name'] + " " + ctx._source['last_name'], ctx._source['last_name'] + " " + ctx._source['first_name']]"}
]
```

Also, transform scripts can be "native", i.e. `java` code, made available to all nodes in the cluster by making your custom classes available in the elasticsearch classpath and registered as native scripts by the settings:

```
script.native.<name>.type=<fully.qualified.class.name>
```

in which case in your mapping you'd register the native script as a transform like so:

```
"transform" : [
    {
        "script" : "<name>",
        "params" : {
            "param1": "val1",
            "param2": "val2"
        },
        "lang": "native"
    }
],
```

Comment: How can I run this transform script? I tried executing PUT myindex/_mappings {{
 "transform" : [
    {"script": "ctx._source['full_name'] = [ctx._source['firstname'] + ' '+ ctx._source['lastname'] ]"}
],
    "properties": {
        "firstname": {
            "type": "text",
        },        "lastname": {
            "type": "text",
        },        "fullname": {
            "type": "text",
        }
        }
        }. This yields an error. "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:

Comment: mapping transform scripts have been long removed from Elasticsearch. I'd suggest upgrading and exploring Ingest Processors instead https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-processors.html